# When I create React-Native new project every time i am facing problem to run react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

[when i run the project i am facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnPwC.png)

i am follow each and every step to create the new react-native project

step-1 : npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
step-2 : cd AwesomeProject
step-3: npx react-native run-android

after aal the process follow then the error are arrive on android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are ona simulator or emulator then in the terminal execute this command

> npx react-native start

and then press **r** in the terminal.

if you are using a real device then type this in terminal

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

and the follow step one

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
38 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 31 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "RZ8N80E3M1D"...
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.demoapp/.MainActivity } again same error arrive plzz help

Comment: check that you mobile and pc have same internet connection